# Why is indexOf(char) is 0 if the value exists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, strict

Why is `firstHalf.indexOf(secondHalfArr[i])`  `0`?

```js
"use strict";
let word = "9999999999",
  len = word.length,
  oddSecondHalfStarter = (len % 2 == 0) ? len / 2 : 1 + len / 2,
  firstHalf = word.substr(0, len / 2),
  secondHalf = word.substr(oddSecondHalfStarter, len),
  firstHalfArr = word.substr(0, len / 2).split(''),
  secondHalfArr = word.substr(oddSecondHalfStarter, len).split(''),
  firstHalfLength = firstHalf.length,
  secondHalfLength = secondHalf.length,
  charsToReplace = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < firstHalfLength; i++) {
  if (firstHalf.indexOf(secondHalfArr[i]) < 1) {
    charsToReplace++;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < secondHalfLength; i++) {
  if (secondHalf.indexOf(firstHalfArr[i]) < 1) {
    charsToReplace++;
  }
}

alert(charsToReplace);
```

Comment: It's `-1` if the value doesn't exist, `0` means it's found on the first character.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns ***-1*** if the value to search for never occurs. The `indexOf()` method is case sensitive.

---

Make sure to use `!== -1` in your statements for valid results.

**Example:**

```
for (let i = 0; i < secondHalfLength; i++) {
  if (secondHalf.indexOf(firstHalfArr[i]) !== -1) {
    charsToReplace++;
  }
}
```